# Configuring Typescript project with webpack

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack

Hello I would like to configure Typescript with composite config and webpack (the code was working well when using a single *tsconfig.json*). I precise that I am TypeScript newbie and rusted in javascript. I have difficulties to obtain my outputs json files.

**EDIT**: I added a bit more configuration and changed the directory structure for something better I believe

My project structure:

```
    tsconfig.base.json
    tsconfig.json
    tsconfig.base.json
    webpack.config.json
    |--model
       |--tsconfig.json
       |--src
         |--foo
            |--x.ts
            |--...
         |--bar
            |--y.ts
            |--...
            |--...
   |--control
       |--tsconfig.json
       |--src
            |--eventHandlerA.ts
            |--eventHandlerB.ts
            |--...
   |--app1
       |--tsconfig.json
       |--src
            |--app1.ts
   |--app1
       |--tsconfig.json
       |--src
            |--app2.ts
```

My desired output are 2 files "app1.js" and "app2.js". Both of them rely on a "controller" package which relies on a "model" package.
I would like to run at least the following commands:

- npm run build #builds the javascript (can be reused for unit testing and package)
- npm run package #builds and copy the output app1.js and app2.js in a delivery directory. I must be able to include only those js files to run my application in a webpage.

Content of *./tsconfig.js*:

```
{
    "references": [
        {
            "path": "app1"
        },
        {
            "path": "app2"
        }
    ],
    "include": []
}
```

Content of *./tsconfig.base.js*:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "composite": true
        "declaration": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "jsx": "react",
    }
}
```

Content of */tsconfig.js*:

```
{
   "files": [],
    "include": [],
    "references": [
        {
            "path": "app1"
        },

        {
            "path": "app2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Content of *./webpack.conf.js*

```
module.exports = {
    mode: "production",
    // Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
    devtool: "source-map",

    resolve: {
        // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx"],
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "ts-loader"
                    }
                ]
            },
            // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
            {
                enforce: "pre",
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: "source-map-loader"
            }
        ]
    },

    // When importing a module whose path matches one of the following, just
    // assume a corresponding global variable exists and use that instead.
    // This is important because it allows us to avoid bundling all of our
    // dependencies, which allows browsers to cache those libraries between builds.
    externals: {
        "react": "React",
        "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
    }
};
```

content of *package.json*

```
{
  "name": "abc",
  "version": "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  "scripts": {
    "test": "npm run build && jest", 
    "build": "tsc -b",
    "clean": "tsc -b --clean",
    "rebuild": "npm run clean && npm run build"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "toto",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  }
}
```

If I run npm run build, I have import failures. To analyze it I ran /*tsc -b control*/:

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module 'x' or its corresponding type declarations.

4 import * as x from 'x'
```

I tried to modify my import in several ways but I always have a failure on the import.
How to import a class (which is exported) from a composite "project" to another using absolute path?

Thank you for helping

Comment: TypeScript imports are relative to the file that imports them, so you'll need to use `../model/foo/x` instead of `src/model/foo/x`. Otherwise you're on the right track, keep trying!

Comment: I am using absolute path for import. In src/model/bar/y.ts, I would like to do 
import * as y from 'foo/x' but I still get the same message, as if the path resolution was done from the root of the project instead of each tsconfig.json directory

Answer (score 0):

To use absolute paths try to configure your `tsconfig.json` file with `baseUrl` and `paths`:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "declaration": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "jsx": "react",
        "baseUrl": "../../", /// <--- baseUrl gives a path from the tsconfig to the root
        "paths": {
            "src/*": [ "../../src/*" ] /// <--- paths specify src/* is inside the src folder, which is ../../ relative to the tsconfig
        }
    },
    "include": [
        "./**/*.ts",
        "./**/*.tsx"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear, I would like the absolute path to be from the current "package" (ie root of each tsconfig.json). Do I still need to set a baseUrl for that?

Comment: If i do, i get:
Cannot write file 'C:/workspace/Project/dist/tsconfig.tsbuildinfo' because it will overwrite '.tsbuildinfo' file generated by referenced project 'C:/workspace/Project/src/model'
I believe it means I have to create a "dist" directory per "package", it is possible to set a generic target for outDir in the tsconfig.base.json like 'dist/<package-name>'?